# Overlap ListBox Items

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two listboxes that are very close together, one on top and one on bottom.  Is it possible to have one of the listbox items on the top listbox overlap the listbox below?

Comment: Why would you ever want to do that ? If you really want to, here's a clue: negative margins...

Comment: @Thomas I believe he is wanting to push the templated item outside the ListBox scope, not pushing the ListBox itself over the other ListBox. Setting the template on the item to negative margins would force all templated items to use that strange margin, not just the last one. I guess you could apply a single template to the last item. Either way no idea why you would want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, like this?  If so, a negative top margin is the answer:

```
<DockPanel>
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="{x:Type Button}"
                TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="50" />
        </Style>
    </DockPanel.Resources>
    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button>Foo</Button>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button>Bar</Button>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button>Baz</Button>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button>Bat</Button>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <ListBox DockPanel.Dock="Top" Margin="0, -10, 0, 0">
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button>Foo</Button>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button>Bar</Button>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button>Baz</Button>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Button>Bat</Button>
        </ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>

    <TextBlock />
</DockPanel>
```