# How to span multiple rows in a listbox

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, mvvm-light

I have created a custom control that displays a composite collection on a grid panel. It looks something like this:

[image]

The 'slots' behind are a uniform 1 row apart and span 1 row each. The 'items' on top can be created at any row and can span multiple rows.

I would like to implement the functionality of *SelectedItems* from the Selector class on the first collection of 'slots'.

Can I derive from Selector (e.g., a listbox) and still create something like the second collection overlayed over the first?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a composite collection. Create a base class or interface and make a single collection of that type. Then extend that class or implement that interface in each of your various different objects that you want to display. Now you'll be able to add each of them into your single collection and just use a normal `ListBox` with `SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Extended` or `SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple`.

Comment: Thanks - and the ListBox will have no trouble displaying one item laid over another?

Comment: That will depend on your `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`, but you can find out more details here: [Overlap ListBox Items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885410/overlap-listbox-items).